# ClickOnce - MinimumRequiredVersion not set and ApplicationVersion not updating

Tags: msbuild, clickonce

Im using MSBuild to publish and deploy a clickonce application. For updating the MinimumRequiredVersion and ApplicationVersion, I have the following target:

```
<Target
Name="FixApplicationVersion"
DependsOnTargets="GetBuildRevision"
BeforeTargets="GenerateDeploymentManifest">
  <Message Text="FixApplicationVersion"/>
  <PropertyGroup>
      <ApplicationVersion>$(ApplicationVersion.Replace('*', '$(BuildRevision)'))</ApplicationVersion>
      <MinimumRequiredVersion>$(ApplicationVersion)</MinimumRequiredVersion>      
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Message Text="MinReq: $(MinimumRequiredVersion)"/>
  <Message Text="ApplicationVer: $(ApplicationVersion)"/>
  <Message Text="BuildRev: $(BuildRevision)"/>
</Target>
```

But after the publish is done, the manifest file (.application) does not have the updated ApplicationVersion (it just has the original base version set as 1.0.0.0), and there is no MinimumRequiredVersion set, so my application wouldnt update even if the ApplicationVersion was set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, look at your project properties. Make sure you check "Automatically increment revision with each publish"
on the Publish tab.